# Finding the render route if validation fails in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a basic survey tool as my first Rails project. 
At the moment I am working on the validation for submitting a new answer to a survey question. The following is my answer model.

```
class Answer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :participant
  validates :text, presence: true,
            length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 100 }
end
```

I have set up an if statement that takes you to the next question if passes validation. My problem is I'm not sure what to render inside the else for this statement.

For similar validation in other controllers I have written the render statement to be the pages URL. For example: View all questions + add new question are rendered on the studies/id page. So if question validation fails then render will be 'studies/show'.

The URL to add a new answer looks like this.
`http://localhost:3000/studies/20/questions/47/answers/new`

For more context here is some of my code:

```
*Answers Controller*

class AnswersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @study = Study.find(params[:study_id])
    @question = @study.questions.find(params[:question_id])
    @participant = find_participant
    @answer = @question.answers.build(participant: @participant)
  end

  def create
    @study = Study.find(params[:study_id])
    @question = @study.questions.find(params[:question_id])
    @answer = @question.answers.build(answer_params)

    if @answer.save
      next_question = @question.next_question
      redirect_to next_question_path(next_question, @answer) if next_question.present?

    else
      #I want to render the current page the participant is on to display errors here.
    end
  end  

  ***some private functions here***

end
```

```
* New Answer View *
<div class="wrap">
  <h1 class="med-header"><%= @question.question %></h1>

  <%= form_with model: @answer, url: study_question_answers_path(@study, @question), local: true do |form| %>
    <%= form.hidden_field :participant_id %>

    <% @question.answers.each do |answer| %>
        <% if answer.errors.any? %>
          <div id="error_explanation">
            <h2>
              <%= pluralize(answer.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
              this answer from being saved:
            </h2>
            <ul>
              <% answer.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
              <% end %>
            </ul>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>

    <%= form.text_area :text %><br>
    <%= form.submit %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

What do I render in the else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cheap way of doing this:

```
   if @answer.save
      next_question = @question.next_question
      redirect_to next_question_path(next_question, @answer) if next_question.present?
    else
      flash[:notice] = @answer.errors.full_messages.first 
      render :new 
    end
```

`render :new` will render the `new` view as you can infer.

Anecdotally, your `next_question_path(next_question, @answer) if next_question.present?` is an unlocked gate if there's no `next_question` :)

Comment: Thank you SO much for this! I will look at refactoring that other line too. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

`create` generates the object and saves. new only generates the object.
If `@answer.save` fails in this situation,

- we need to show the form back to the user. `format.html { render :new }`
- If use JSON you need show errors  `format.json { render json: @anwser.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }`

Reference : [How CURD Work](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)